# Django LRU_Cache with API Calls

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I'm trying to use the Reddit API via PRAW (https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) with Django, and am thinking of trying to use functools `lru_cache` decorator to implement some kind of caching so I can cache the results of similar API calls to reduce overall calls being made. I've never done anything like this so I've been mainly following examples of implementing the `@lru_cache` decorator.

I have 3 files that are primarily involved with the API calls / display here. I have:

**account.html**

```
{% extends 'myapp/base.html' %}
<h1> {{ name }} </h1>
<h3> {{ comment_karma }} </h3>

<h5> Top Posts </h5>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th> Post </th>
        <th> Subreddit </th>
    </tr>
    {% for s in top_submissions %}
        <tr>
           <td> {{ s.title }} </td>
            <td> {{ s.subreddit }} </td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

**views.py**

```
from . import reddit

reddit = reddit.Reddit()

def account_page():
    context = reddit.details(request.user.reddit_username)
    return render(request, 'stats/dashboard.html', context)
```

**reddit.py**

```
 from functools import lru_cache

 class Reddit:
    def __init__(self):
        self.praw = praw.Reddit(
            client_id = CLIENT_ID,
            client_secret = CLIENT_SECRET,
            user_agent = USER_AGENT
        )

     @lru_cache(maxsize = 256)
     def details(self, redditor):
        redditor = self.praw.redditor(redditor)

        overview = {
            'name': redditor.name,
            'comment_karma': redditor.comment_karma,
            'top_submissions': redditor.submissions.top(limit=10),
        }
        return overview
```

Here's the problem: when I don't have the lru_cache, then everything works fine and all the data comes in as always. However, when I do put the lru_cache option, then only the name and comment_karma come, while the submissions (an iterable list) just does not display on my page (so I assume it doesn't end up having any values).

Am I using lru_cache wrong? Essentially, my goal is if a `redditor` is passed into the function `overview`, I don't want to keep making the same API calls over and over, but instead want to put it into the cache and pull that same data if it's in the cache.

Comment: Try expanding the submissions.top object first: `list(redditor.submissions.top(limit=10))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PRAW returns generator objects that are lazily evaluated. You want to evaluate them inside your cached function. Otherwise, after the generator is exhausted, you can't get the results again.

So the working version should look like this:

```py
     @lru_cache(maxsize = 256)
     def details(self, redditor):
        redditor = self.praw.redditor(redditor)

        overview = {
            'name': redditor.name,
            'comment_karma': redditor.comment_karma,
            'top_submissions': list(redditor.submissions.top(limit=10)),
        }
        return overview
```

`list(redditor.submissions.top(limit=10))` will consume the generator and the cached result will contain the list, rather than the generator object which can only be consumed once.

Comment: Ah I didn't think to consider that thank you! That allows them to be displayed everytime. The new problem I seem to have with this is in my views.py, if I pass in a random reddit user, and keep navigating to the account page, it uses the cached data. But if I use another reddit user, then switch back to the original, it seems to still go through the `details` function (I have print statements set up in it). Looks like it's not adhering to the 256 size for the lru cache?

Comment: There may be several causes for that. Some things to consider: caching works by the `__hash__` of the objects passed as arguments. So, if those objects don't hash the same, you'll get a cache miss. The other thing is that, depending how you run django, you may have several processes (or even several separate systems altogether, eventually) and they may not share the same memory space (and thus use different caches). You probably want to consider using the builtin [cache framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/cache/) or your own db caching for a robust solution.

Comment: Thanks! I've been going through the Django documentation that you linked and have been looking at the low-level API cache calls (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/cache/#the-low-level-cache-api). So I try now to do something like `cache.set(request.user.reddit_username, context, 30)` (so username as the key, context dict as the value, and 30 second timeout). This however gives me `Can't pickle local object 'UserSubreddit._dict_depreciated_wrapper.<locals>.wrapper'`. Searching this error hasn't given me much, do you know anything about it? The context dictionary holdes the api return